# Python Decorator With Try/Except Not Raising Error

Tags: python, try-catch, python-decorators

I am experimenting with Python Decorators in order to understand what it happening and I have hit a head-scratcher.

My code is this (python 2.7.6):

```
import traceback
def dec(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if flag:
                print 'flagged'
            else:
                print 'unflagged'
        except NameError as e:
            print 'error?'
            raise
        finally:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

@dec
def foo(x):
    print x

foo(3)
```

when run, the output is:

```
error?
3
```

I expected that calling foo(3) would raise:

```
NameError: global name 'flag' is not defined
```

Why is the "raise" not raising? Clearly, the error is caught - the print from the Except block is executed...

Comment: This seems to have something to do with the timing of exiting the finally block - "A finally clause is always executed before leaving the try statement, whether an exception has occurred or not. When an exception has occurred in the try clause and has not been handled by an except clause (or it has occurred in a except or else clause), it is re-raised after the finally clause has been executed. The finally clause is also executed “on the way out” when any other clause of the try statement is left via a break, continue or return statement." Not sure why the error never gets raised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` in the `finally` overrides and cancels any exception or function return that might have triggered the `finally` block. This is documented in the [Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> If `finally` is present, it specifies a ‘cleanup’ handler. The `try`
>   clause is executed, including any `except` and `else` clauses. If an
>   exception occurs in any of the clauses and is not handled, the
>   exception is temporarily saved. The `finally` clause is executed. If
>   there is a saved exception, it is re-raised at the end of the
>   `finally` clause. **If the `finally` clause raises another exception or
>   executes a `return` or `break` statement, the saved exception is
>   discarded:**

For example:

```
def f():
    try:
        1/0
    finally:
        return

f() # No exception

def g():
    try:
        return 1
    finally:
        return 0

g() # 0

def h():
    try:
        raise NameError
    finally:
        raise TypeError

h() # TypeError
```

Comment: I didn't read far enough (and my head was swimming trying to follow the logic anyway).